# Why i can't initialize quartz.net adoJobStore with oracle?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, quartz.net, quartz.net-3.0

I'm trying to setup quartz.net AdoJobStore with oracle.
I have a valid schema with tables for quartz.
But every time i'm facing the same Exception "Could not Initialize DataSource: default" at the last line of this code.

```
        NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "TestScheduler";
        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "instance_one";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";
        properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = "Data Source=//192.168.0.221:1521/ESPDB;User Id=quartz;Password=quartz";
        properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "OracleODP-20";
        //
        ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
        IScheduler scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
```

Same exception i was faced when i'm trying to use config file.
I'm using version 3.0 of quartz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify last property as follows

```
properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "OracleODP";
```

It worked for me.
I think OracleODP-20 could be the old value of Oracle data provider for previous version of Quartz.net as you can read [here](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/2017/12/30/quartznet-3.0-released.html).